# User profile service error: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I am getting an error with the User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization timer job on one (of two) of our web front ends. Couldn't find any info on the internet specific to this problem. Any help is appreciated

> 07/10/2015 13:05:51.03    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x265C)
>
> 0x0490  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles
>     ohvc    Exception
>
> failure in SynchContentDB System.ArgumentException: An
>   item with the same key has already been added.     at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value,
>   Boolean add)     at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)     at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SychronizeModifiedProfiles(Guid
>   partitionID, DateTime lastRunTime, DateTime& sqlTime)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SynchContentDB()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean
>   fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock
>   catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock) StackTrace:  at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll:
>   (sig=80530fbd-8cb8-46a1-ba61-2bfa43047c2b|2|microsoft.office.server.native.pdb,
>   offset=131D6) at Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll:
>   (offset=21C6D)    1ab5189d-464c-701d-8f91-4defdf70401b

and

> 07/10/2015 13:05:51.03    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x265C)
>
> 0x0490  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles
>
> 5555    Critical    Failure trying to synch web application
>   c2eccf16-0b6b-4559-98c8-6823ca9685ab, ContentDB
>   4a249c9f-35bf-4651-811e-f12cc5846693  Exception message was
>   System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key,
>   TValue value, Boolean add)     at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)     at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SychronizeModifiedProfiles(Guid
>   partitionID, DateTime lastRunTime, DateTime& sqlTime)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ContentDBSynchronizer.SynchContentDB()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Diagnostics.FirstChanceHandler.ExceptionFilter(Boolean
>   fRethrowException, TryBlock tryBlock, FilterBlock filter, CatchBlock
>   catchBlock, FinallyBlock finallyBlock)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.WSSProfileSyncJob.Execute()  1ab5189d-464c-701d-8f91-4defdf70401b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the user profile sync to update the user information lists in all our site collections now. It turns out our entire web app was excluded from the sync process somehow. I ran the following command:

```
Stsadm -o sync -excludewebapps ""
```

and all of a sudden the dates changed from 1/1/001 to today's date when I ran listolddatabases.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions in this situation.

1. Clear the [SharePoint Config cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx) on all WFE servers and then run the full sync.
2. Run old fashioned [stsadm.exe -o sync](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263196.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) command to delete the old sync info and re sync them.

   `stsadm.exe -o sync -listolddatabases 0`
   `stsadm.exe -o sync -deleteolddatabases 1`

stsadm.exe -help sync

Comment: Believe it or not I was going to clear the SP cache on the servers this weekend due to another issue, related to the search service, on the same server. I'll let you know if it clears up the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I did both and the error is still there. After doing the deleteolddatabases I check them again (listolddatabases) and there were a bunch there all with a sync date of 1/1/0001. Not sure if that means anything

Comment: that's mean your DBs are still out of sync.

Comment: Any recommendations, that is if deleteolddatabases isn't working?

Comment: I looked at this closer and it appears only one of the content databases (out of 23) is syncing. I'll keep digging in to a solution for this and post whatever I find out.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, i have removed HTTPS bindings (32844) in IIS for SharePoint Web Services which caused this error. Added the HTTPS bindings again and it worked for me.

Ref : http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/07/sharepoint-web-services-error-item-with.html